# Get anonymous users with Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am using Cloud Functions to manage the database and the auth in my project. I followed the example https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron to delete inactive users in my app. I want to get only the anonymous users that were inactive for some time. I don't know to make the query to the identity toolkit to filter only the correct ones. Does anybody help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to write the account auth provider(s) into your database at the time of login, then use that to further filter the set of accounts that should be deleted.  This way, you won't have to take the time to [query each uid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) to find out what its [providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord#providerData) are.

Comment: Thanks! I already try that and works fine. My question is in order to improve the situation and reduce the queries to the database. I will try to tackle the problem with the info you give me in the second link. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Admin SDK `listUsers` API to list all users and then inspect if the account has no provider data (assuming you don't use custom authentication)/no emails and inspect the metadata `lastSignInTime`. However, as Firebase sessions are indefinite, that does not guarantee the account is inactive:
Listing users: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users

User record metadata which contains last sign in time: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord#metadata

Comment: I will try, thanks. Although, in the example I followed, the queries are done to the identity toolkit. Do you know where are the full fields I could query? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? identity toolkit is also used in these APIs. It is a shared backend for the legacy Google Identity Toolkit and Firebase Auth. The admin SDK APIs abstract this for you. You don't need to know what goes on underneath.

Comment: In the example, the following line queries the fields you want to obtain.       uri: `https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/downloadAccount?fields=users/localId,users/lastLoginAt,nextPageToken&access_token=' + accessToken` . In this case, it obtains users/localId and users/lastLoginAt. I want to know which other fields could obtain