# How to delete anonymously authorized user in firebase console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firestore in my project.
I made a login system which user can login anonymously.
However, I realized that there's no function to delete users who are already registered anonymously.
I wonder if firestore support that kind of function in firebase console (I mean, firebase website).
Should I delete registered users manually on the firebase website?

Comment: There's no harm in deleting them manually.

Comment: @camden_kid, I know, but the problem is that it was for a test.
So I have to delete all of users I registered anonymously, and the number of registered anonymous users are more than 4000...
Can not delete all of them manually.

Comment: Sorry, I was answering the last sentence of your question. If it was me, I would create a firebase cloud function to delete them.

Comment: Cloud function? I didn’t know it could delete registered user. I haven’t cloud function in my project. Thanks I’ll read about it. Can you give me some advice about it?

Comment: Sure. This is the setup - firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started. This shows how to manipulate users - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users. And this may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664848/get-anonymous-users-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Comment: This post is 2 years old but may probably help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640574/how-to-bulk-delete-firebase-anonymous-users

Comment: @camden_kid Thank you, it was very helpful!